# Asterisk Play a file while calling for curl

Tags: asterisk

In my dialplan I need to call a php 


exten => 6666,n,Set(foo=${CURL(http://reports.cr.mrgroup.in/IVR/sp.php?tid=${tid})})


it gives reponse after 1 min or 2min , I want to play a music file in these times 
please give me some idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is use `StartMusicOnHold()` -- I use this when I've got other processing I need to do (in one case, I do it while there's a long TTS conversion)

You can find more help by running `asterisk*CLI> core show application StartMusicOnHold`

An example looks like this:

```
exten => test,1,Answer()
same =>       n,StartMusicOnHold()
same =>       n,Wait(20)            ; Do processing here.
same =>       n,StopMusicOnHold()
same =>       n,Hangup()
```

Also your music on hold configuration will live @ `/etc/asterisk/musiconhold.conf` -- if you install the sample configuration, it will be there with documentation inline.